# I need to make my program which is working with Strings on Python faster! Up to 1000ms

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, optimization

I have created a program which find a MAX and MIN string value from the end of it on PYTHON. I needed to speed it up to 1000ms on competition. I do not know how to make it faster. What i need to do?

```
stop=input()
a=[stop]
ar=[]
while True:
    line = input()
    if (line.strip()==stop):
        break

    a.append(line)
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    ar.append((a[i])[::-1])
print((min(ar))[::-1])
print((max(ar))[::-1])
```

The program stops input when meet copy of first String input value

Input and output for example:

INPUT:

```
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
January
```

OUTPUT:

```
June
February
```

INPUT:

```
09
18
27
36
45
54
63
72
81
90
09
```

OUTPUT:

```
90
09
```

I have already tried to optimize code and its the last version of it

Comment: How can June be the maximum value and February the minimum?

Comment: How much too slow is it? Is this online for testing somewhere?

Comment: Keep track of the minimum and maximum values as they're being entered, that way you don't have to call `min()` and `max()` at the end.

Comment: @JohnGordon ~ but that would result in a branched condition on every iteration of the loop. That can't be faster.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy You think `min()` and `max()` _aren't_ doing conditional branching in a loop?!

Comment: @JohnGordon ~ yeah, A loop in C... not python.

Comment: What are the limits for how many strings there are and for how long the strings are?

Comment: Your edit shows that you were here an hour ago. Why not answer our questions? Do you not actually want help?

Answer (score 0):

Your challenge seems to be to:

1. create a list of reversed strings
2. find `min` and `max`

By only doing those steps you should be better off than where you are.

```
#supporting data
stop = input()
a    = []

#1 create a list of reversed strings
while (ln := input()) != stop:
    a.append(ln[::-1])

#2 print min and max
print(min(a)[::-1], max(a)[::-1], sep='\n')
```

According to [this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZK_btswEMaBjnqKr_FgMpCNOF0KA5w7FV26qYLAVEebqEQRFJ3Ez9IlS_sAfZw-TXmUrPxBuZDHu-_I3939_O3P8Ti4p6dfp2g2H_---9OSwRDswTrdCbkvgDEOXlnnT1HIZGpV8U3Nx6Aq3h-OtiN8DSfieKCzjqDwrAGsgeDr7RiD9UIqxUnkFM_rLpD-UWRTb7X35NosYLkZAmxKh6DdgcRNiY6c0HKW63ARCF3ZWlb7_WZXs9AH66IQvU3RQf7HoR9fOQqm_-Los24_nf14fi7AKxzNryok9mK1w_f080jpMtA9hZHaxD9GDAbM6g7jUiHROeyXRBLvVc49UayuJogrxAHxSLij1ASXErwpilt-u7qdQJAAoV2LxLPAZeiZrEQmXayRvFp_c-uUw4ShR7Q9wfZ-CDGfC678yIjrzbrEda-9SDDl3IDdDS8pSyR3XXB7DLenugxO-bKINa7xYWLM5FzKSCF3d5TbpnH0GJsmB7CTPzBPjZn3iWhyYINYwrBO99Q0chrdeYIvk_wP) benchmark, we get results like this:

```
 0.05013751983642578 original
 0.03334331512451172 mine
```